# Index added to view affecting other view

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

I created two views:

- vTest1
- vTest2

The create procedure for each is:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vTest1] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT        Person.EmailAddress.EmailAddress, Person.Person.Title, Person.Person.FirstName, Person.Person.MiddleName, Person.Person.LastName
FROM            Person.Person 
    INNER JOIN  Person.EmailAddress 
    ON Person.Person.BusinessEntityID = Person.EmailAddress.BusinessEntityID
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vTest1] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT        Person.EmailAddress.EmailAddress, Person.Person.Title, Person.Person.FirstName, Person.Person.MiddleName, Person.Person.LastName
FROM            Person.Person 
    INNER JOIN Person.EmailAddress 
    ON Person.Person.BusinessEntityID = Person.EmailAddress.BusinessEntityID
```

Then I run a `SELECT *` from each I get the expected execution plan.

[image: Non-indexed view execution plans]

Now, I add an index to `vTest2`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20161025-205534] ON [dbo].[vTest2]
(
    [EmailAddress] ASC,
    [Title] ASC,
    [FirstName] ASC,
    [MiddleName] ASC,
    [LastName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now when I the select again I find that the added index is being used for both views.

[image: Clustered index view execution plans]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.5" Build="13.0.1711.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="19936.1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" StatementSubTreeCost="0.209696" StatementText="SELECT * FROM dbo.vTest1" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x95D05E881A8B7175" QueryPlanHash="0x16D51AFE3D4CCA61" RetrievedFromCache="true" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="581" CompileCPU="4" CompileMemory="288">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="69408" EstimatedPagesCached="52056" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="6" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="227" EstimateCPU="0.0221262" EstimateIO="0.187569" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="19972" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.209696" TableCardinality="19972">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="EmailAddress" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="Title" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="FirstName" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="MiddleName" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="LastName" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="19972" ActualRowsRead="19972" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="31" ActualCPUms="5" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="256" ActualPhysicalReads="1" ActualReadAheads="250" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="true" Storage="RowStore">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="EmailAddress" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="Title" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="FirstName" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="MiddleName" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="LastName" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Index="[ClusteredIndex-20161025-205534]" IndexKind="ViewClustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                <IndexedViewInfo>
                  <Object Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[Person]" Table="[Person]" />
                  <Object Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[Person]" Table="[EmailAddress]" />
                </IndexedViewInfo>
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="2" StatementEstRows="19936.1" StatementId="2" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" StatementSubTreeCost="0.209696" StatementText="SELECT * FROM dbo.vTest2" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x95D05E881A8B7175" QueryPlanHash="0x16D51AFE3D4CCA61" RetrievedFromCache="true" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="240">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="69408" EstimatedPagesCached="52056" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="6" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="227" EstimateCPU="0.0221262" EstimateIO="0.187569" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="19972" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.209696" TableCardinality="19972">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="EmailAddress" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="Title" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="FirstName" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="MiddleName" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="LastName" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="19972" ActualRowsRead="19972" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="5" ActualCPUms="5" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="256" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="true" Storage="RowStore">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="EmailAddress" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="Title" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="FirstName" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="MiddleName" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Column="LastName" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[vTest2]" Index="[ClusteredIndex-20161025-205534]" IndexKind="ViewClustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                <IndexedViewInfo>
                  <Object Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[Person]" Table="[Person]" />
                  <Object Database="[AdventureWorks2008R2]" Schema="[Person]" Table="[EmailAddress]" />
                </IndexedViewInfo>
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

In the Plan XML I can see that this is actually using the index on vTest2 for both queries.

Why is the `SELECT * FROM dbo.vTest1` using the index defined on `dbo.vTest2`?

PS.  The queries are:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.vTest1
SELECT * FROM dbo.vTest2
```

Comment: Any queries that the indexed view can satisfy can also be chosen by the optimiser. Cool, eh?

Comment: Is that what it's doing?  If so, that is indeed cool... also means that adding an index to a table could affect execution of sprocs which have no relation to that table!  Hope I never have to track a bug caused by that down.

Comment: Underlaying SQL Server engine converts views into their definitions and he's smart enough to discover that you have two identical views.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on (2012,2014,2016)? Also is it Enterprise or Standard?